# my rewriterule's are not working correctly in the htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

Im trying to create pretty urls for a site im currently working on but each time i navigate to the pretty url it tells me the page dont exist, could someone take a look at my code and see what i am missing or doing wrong

I have watched tutorials and searched online for written examples which is how i come up with the code i got but i just cant seem to get it to work

Here is the code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^sub_cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) view_sub_cat.php?tcid=$1&scid=$2 [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: think you need a `$` at the end of the pattern... ie: `^sub_cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$`

Comment: tried that earlier with no result

Comment: and have you set the `RewriteBase`?

Comment: yes unless i have that set wrong, i did forget to add it into my first post, it looks like this RewriteBase /forum/ the site im working on is a sub directory of the main site

Comment: Have you manually tried to GET the view_sub_cat.php URL in the browser? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Also, turn on the logging via `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` in .htaccess temporarily.. and get logs in apache access logs.. in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: Example URL that you are trying to rewrite?

Comment: @hacker315 if i understand correctly about manually GET the page, then yes it works correctly using the GET vars from the URL as the page works its only once i try to rewrite the URL it doesnt seem to work. I will give your second answer a shot

Comment: @CBroe check the first post at the top as i have posted the URL im trying to rewrite

Comment: It only contains your rewrite attempt. Questions of this kind should always contain a _proper_ example of a URL you want to rewrite, like `http://example.com/foo/bar`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these two lines of code to your .htaccess file

```
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: I did originally have that in my code but took it out as it made no difference

Comment: Okay try this.   RewriteRule ^sub_cat/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ./ view_sub_cat.php?tcid=$1&scid=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: still nothing, when i use the new url which would be sub_cat/1/4 it shows my web host's default page